# Проверка наличия прикреплённого товара в сообщении через VK API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Вроде бы разобрался с API ВК, но не могу проверить наличие типа приложения link в сообщении. Пробую так:

```
  case 'message_new': 
$product = $data->object->attachments["type"];

if(isset($product)) { //Если товар отправлен
```

Но не выходит. И как сделать не знаю, поддержка молчит много дней. Не подскажете?

Comment: а что собмтвенно в $product попадает?

Comment: {"type":"message_new","object":{"описание сообщения","attachments":[{"type":"link","link":{"описание товара"}]},"group_id":88053972}. Такой запрос отправляется серверу при получении сообщения с товаром. То есть я проверяю, какого типа link. Немного я смыслю в php, да уж.

Comment: `json_decode` сделали?

Comment: не смыслю* Нет, не сделал. Там из описания сообщения таким же образом берутся и другие данные без decode. А тут нужно?